# Nifi QueryRecord on Array of String contains value

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-calcite

Using Apache Nifi i am trying to figure out how to find records which have a string in an array that start with a value

Given the below array, i would like only record which have a tag that start with '/test2/'

```
[
   {
    "name":"bob",
    "tags":[ "/test1/foo","/alpha"]
   }
   ,
   {
    "name":"bill",
    "tags":[ "/test2/blah","/beta"]
   }

]
```

SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE RPATH_STRING(tags, '/') LIKE '/test2/%'

```
due to java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.Record: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.nifi.serialization.record.Record
```

I've tried a few other permutations, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution with 2 processors (`ScriptedTransformProcessor` -> `QueryRecord`):

**ScriptedTransformProcessor** (add new field `tags_str` - concatenating all of the elements in `tags` with delimiter `|`)

- `Script Language`: `Groovy`
- `Script Body`:

```
record.setValue('tags_str', record.getValue('tags').join("|"))
record
```

Output (JSON):

```json
[ {
  "name" : "bob",
  "tags" : [ "/test1/foo", "/alpha" ],
  "tags_str" : "/test1/foo|/alpha"
}, {
  "name" : "bill",
  "tags" : [ "/test2/blah", "/beta" ],
  "tags_str" : "/test2/blah|/beta"
} ]
```

**QueryRecord** (filter)

- filter (dynamic property):

```sql
SELECT name, tags 
FROM FLOWFILE 
WHERE tags_str LIKE '%/test2/%'
```

output (JSON):

```json
[ {
  "name" : "bill",
  "tags" : [ "/test2/blah", "/beta" ]
} ]
```